# Regarding square-free integers and Euler's function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Let $\phi$ be Euler's totient function. Prove that if $\text{gcd}(\phi(n), n) = 1$, then $n$ is a square free integer.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You need to [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) for your question. Right now, it just looks like you want somebody to do your homework for you; that's not what this site is for. If you add some appropriate context, we will be happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey and welcome to MSE.

I guess you might be aware of the multiplicative properties of φ(n).

Start by writing $n=p_1^{r_1}...p_m^{r_m}$
It follows that $φ(n)=φ(p_1^{r_1})φ(p_2^{r_2})...φ(p_m^{r_m})$, and we have that $φ(p_i^{r_i})=p_i^{r_i-1}(p_i-1)$.

This means that if the $gcd(n, φ(n))=1$, then it means that $r_i=1$ for all i, otherwise $p_i$ would be a common factor.